# Does the d8 shell's console.log support format specifiers?

Tags: javascript, v8

d8 is a minimal shell for running JavaScript programs using V8. Does the implementation of console.log in d8 support format specifiers/characters? I tried to use a format specifier, and it printed the specifier and the variable value (as shown below).

```
d8> for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)  {console.log('Number is %d', i);}
Number is %d 0
Number is %d 1
Number is %d 2
Number is %d 3
Number is %d 4
Number is %d 5
Number is %d 6
Number is %d 7
Number is %d 8
Number is %d 9
undefined
```

I see a similar question here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/10292 ... Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: No. The d8 `console` is nothing but a really thin wrapper around output, it doesn't have any fancy functionality built in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from your experiment, d8 does not support format specifiers. It wouldn't want to support anything that's not legal JavaScript.

Speaking of which: JavaScript has "[template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)" since a while. So without placing any requirements on d8 or `console.log`, anywhere you have strings you can do:

```
let i = 42;
console.log(`Number is ${i}`);
let just_a_string = `1 + 2 = ${1+2}`;
console.log(just_a_string);
console.assert(just_a_string === "1 + 2 == 3");
```

If you were hoping for more advanced formatting, like C-style `%5d`, AFAIK you'll have to build that yourself. If you're interested in floating-point numbers, [`.toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) and [`.toPrecision`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision) might be helpful.

Comment: The answer has been accepted. This v8.dev says that d8 stands for Debug8 - https://v8.dev/docs/d8 ... What say you?

Comment: Hmm ... Looks like the v8.dev docs changed overnight removing the "Debug8" wording. This question never really about a pedantic exercise ... but the answer remains.